# Simple traits not working as intended (MSVC vs gcc & clang) and how to fix it

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

The following example features simple traits that can be manually associated with a class.
If no explicit definition is given, a compiler error shall be issued.

On MSVC this works as intended (*insert joke*), while gcc&clang always instantiate the general `GetDef()` with the `static_assert` and thus always fail to compile. The standard allegedly requires this.

How can I fix this to work on any (*insert adjectives*) compiler? Please refrain from posting over-complicated workarounds, there must be a simple way.

```
template <typename T>
auto constexpr GetDef()
{
    static_assert( false, "undefined type" );
}

class MyClass {};    
class MyDefinedClass {};    

template <>
auto constexpr GetDef<int>()
{
    return 1;
}

template<typename T> struct Trait {};

template <>
auto constexpr GetDef<MyDefinedClass>()
{
    return Trait<MyDefinedClass>();
}

int main() 
{
    using Def1 = decltype( GetDef<int>() );               // these fail on gcc/clang
    using Def2 = decltype( GetDef<MyDefinedClass>() );

    //using Def3 = decltype( GetDef<MyClass>() );         // <== this one must fail
}
```

Here is a [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vhYeT3) link.

Comment: why do you need both `GetDef` and `Trait` ?

Comment: please include the compiler errors. I dont udnerstand how you come to the conclusion that `using Def1  = decltype ...` fails. I get a different error here: https://godbolt.org/z/q3T86v

Comment: @idclev463035818 the stuff in main doesn't seem relevant. Thing is, if you switch to latest MSVC it compiles.

Comment: "stuff in main is not relevant" in your question you write something else...

Comment: @idclev463035818 not my question :p, I should have written "doesn't seem relevant"

Comment: @deW1 oh sorry, time for a break I suppose

Comment: @idclev463035818 your answer was good, but I'd also like to know why MSVC lets it through :)

Comment: Guys, let's concentrate for once!